# Javascript code doesnt work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vZMyS/
EDIT: thanks to Buck Doyle i made an appropriate if else with different versions of the script for chrome and firefox/opera. Now it just doesnt work with IE.

Script is supossed to make user able to scroll down/up to scrollpoints that are specified in the "var scrollKeys", using up/down keyboard keys, it does work in chrome, but it doesnt in other browsers.

Any idea whats wrong here? How could i fix this code in order to make it work in firefox/opera/ie8+?

**html**

```
<div class="big">
<div class="box1">
    <input type="text" name="input1" class="input1" />
</div>
<div class="box2">
    <input type="text" name="input2" class="input1" />
</div>
<div class="box1">
    <input type="text" name="input3" class="input1" />
</div>
<div class="box2">
    <input type="text" name="input4" class="input1" />
</div>
</div>​
```

**css**

```
.big {width:400px; height:4000px; float:left;}
.box1 {width:400px; height:1000px; background-color:#ccc; float:left;}
.box2 {width:400px; height:1000px; background-color:#ddd; float:left;}
.input1 {width:120px; height:16px; float:left;}
```

**javascript**

```
var scrollKeys = new Array('0', '1000', '2000', '3000');
$('body').on('keyup', function(event) {
    var keypressed = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    var curScroll = $('body').scrollTop();
    var keys = scrollKeys.length;
    var moved = false;
    for (i = 0; i < keys; i++) {
        //console.log(scrollKeys[i]);
        if (moved == false) {
            if (keypressed == 40 && i != (keys - 1) && parseInt(scrollKeys[i]) < curScroll && parseInt(scrollKeys[i + 1]) > curScroll) {
                $('body').animate({
                    scrollTop : (parseInt(scrollKeys[i + 1]))
                }, 'fast', function() {});
                console.log('down');
                moved = true;
            } else if (keypressed == 38 && i != 0 && parseInt(scrollKeys[i]) > curScroll && parseInt(scrollKeys[i - 1]) < curScroll) {
                $('body').animate({
                    scrollTop : (parseInt(scrollKeys[i - 1]))
                }, 'fast', function(){});
                console.log('up');
                moved = true;
            }
        }
    }
});​
```

​

Comment: Please add your code here as well and explain what the issue is about. What are "scrollpoints"? What does the code do? What happens and what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vZMyS/1/) is a fork of your fiddle that works in Firefox. But now it doesn’t work in Chrome. The important thing is that I changed it to scroll `html` instead of `body`.

Comment: it should work in opera aswell, thanks :) so its just IE left... btw any reference on this?

Comment: It was only vague memories that made me try changing the selector. But [this smooth scrolling code](http://css-tricks.com/examples/SmoothPageScroll/) tries both `html` and `body`, so it’s definitely a Thing. Testing in IE is a pain for me due to weird hardware problems, so I can’t help you there, sorry.

Comment: That fork works in IE9, and once I commented the references to console (which isn't enabled by default), it worked in IE8.